# push method not working

Tags: javascript, push

i've been loosing my hair over this one. I want to create a dynamic array depending on how many  tags my main  has inside. Please Help me!

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="image-slider">
   <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/slider1.png"></a>
   <a href="http://www.phpacademy.org"><img src="images/slider2.png"></a>
   <a href="http://www.ign.com"><img src="images/slider3.png"></a>
   <a href="http://www.w3schools.com"><img src="images/slider4.png"></a>
   <a href="http://www.nfl.com"><img src="images/slider5.png"></a>
</div>
```

Here is my JS

```
container = document.getElementById('image-slider');
containerLength = container.childNodes.length;
images = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<=containerLength;i++){
if (container.childNodes[i].nodeName == 'A') {
    alert(container.childNodes[i]);// here I get the desired value
    images.push(container.childNodes[i]);
          //this doesn't work even if i use images.push('Hello');
}
}
alert(images[0]); //doesn't even pops out
// if I do it like this.... i get the desired result! I don't know why! but this is not what i want
images.push(container.childNodes[1]);
alert(images[0]);
```

Comment: Protip: Use `container.children` to only get elements. `childNodes` gets elements and text nodes, which you then have to manually filter.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire problem can be circumvented easily:

```
var images = document.getElementById("image-slider").children;
```

Magic :p

Comment: wow!!! Thank you very much!! you saved me! do you know any good resource for javascript aside from W3Schools?

Comment: W3Schools is actually the [***worst*** resource out there](http://w3fools.com/). That link will tell you why, and also advise you on places to find good information.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the debugger on this you'll notice that you are trying to reference the 12th element in the collection when the collection only has 11.

```
for(var i=0;i<=containerLength;i++)
```

should be

```
for(var i=0;i<containerLength;i++)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot VARAK I tried the code above and worked just fine.. :)